# AJAX injected content doesn't apply css from containing page

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I have implemented AJAX on a new website which loads and inserts Wordpress page content using AJAX.

Problem: css styles which are loaded already loaded in the page head are not being loaded.

If I click a page, some effects and transitions don't load - when checking the element, the css isn't visible. I then click "reload" which loads the page normally, and everything works perfectly.

Site: http://murrayfredericks.oleymedia.com/projects/

Click "Greenlands" -> "Information" - sometimes the font wont load (because bootstrap.css doesn't load and other times it doesn't load in columns because the js_composer.min.css doesn't load)
Reload the page and voila - problem resolved - all styles are loaded?

E.g.
When I click the "Information" page and view the source for the first column element:

```
<div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-3 catlistli visible">
```

This is what I see:

[image]

Then, when I reload, I view the exact same element and this is what I see:

[image]

NOTE: See now that the js_composer.min.css is now being applied to the same element and is formatting it properly so that it looks how it should look.

I have tried adding the css after the fact with the following code but that doesn't seem to do anything either:

```
jQuery('<link>')
    .appendTo('head')
    .attr({
        type: 'text/css', 
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: '/wp-content/themes/html5blank-child/css/bootstrap.min.css'
    });
```

Before (on initial AJAX load):

[image]

After (Once you refresh page):

[image]

Comment: I am also seeing the content as expected on OSX Chrome Version 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit)

Comment: I don't know what you're looking at or checking but it most definitely is not working fine. If you go to murrayfredericks.oleymedia.com and then once loaded, click "Projects" -> "Greenland" -> "Information" - every time, for me and every other PC in world that has tested it, either the content loads in Times New Roman (wrong font) OR the instead of 4 columns it loads as 1 - it changes between which css doesn't load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem/solution.

The project/gallery page was loading some js that was breaking the site - once I removed this code, it started working properly